# Silanization of glass cover slips

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry

I was trying to silanize the glass coverslips using a protocol mentioned in some papers that say to make up a solution of 595µl N-trimethoxysilylpropyl-N,N,N-trimethylammonium chloride (TCMP-TAC) and 216µl of vinyltrimethoxysilane (VTS) in 300ml ultrapure water and incubate overnight at 65ºC.

However, I don't know about the concentrations of each of the components of the mixture containing TCMP-TAC and VTS individually. Gelest provides TCMP-TAC in 50 % methanol and VTS as a solid. How should I go about making the individual components?